# In what order are recursive calls stacked

Tags: javascript, recursion

Given  this recursive function that raises a `base` number to the power of `exponent` :

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0)
    return 1;
  else  return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}
```

in what order is the call stack processed in memory.

Comment: Do it on paper.  Call it with an exponent of 2.

Comment: Because when `exponent` is `0`, only the *innermost* call returns `1`. Not "the whole function".

Comment: The function **does** return `1`, back to the previous call of `power`, that called the "last step", where `exponent - 1` is `0`. That step in turn then returns `base * 1`, back to the next higher step which then is `base * base * 1`, and so on.

Comment: Google "how recursion works" and watch a first or two hits from youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you called it with `exponent` equals to two or more, 
eventually `exponent` will be zero and the last call of the function will return `1`. Then the second-to-last call will return `base * 1`, which is `base`. then the third-to-last call will return `base * base * 1` (which is the square of `base`), and so on until the original call will return the power you requested.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of calling that function:

```
 power (2,3) // base =2 , exponent = 3

    first call => (exponent is 3) !=0 // if is not true

        return base * power (2 , 2) //exponent now equals 2

        second Call => (exponent is 2) != 0 

            return base * power(2,1) // exponent now equals 1

            third call => (exponent is 1) != 0

                    return base * power(2,0) // exponent now equals 0

                        fourth call => (exponent is 0) == 0

                            return 1;

now replace the variables with its values
fourth = 1
third = base * fourth
second = base * third
first  = base * second

third = 2 * 1
second = 2 * 2
first = 2 * 4
```